# If $f$ is Lipschitz, $X_n$ converges in distribution and $d(X_n,Y_n)$ converges stochastically to $0$, then $\limsup_{n\to\infty}E[|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|]=0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory

Let

- $(E,d)$ be a separable metric space
- $X,X_n,Y_n$ be random variables with values in $E$ such that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $\left(d(X_n,Y_n)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges stochastically to $0$
- $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded and Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $K$, i.e. $$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\le \min\left\{Kd(x,y),\left\|f\right\|_\infty\right\}$$

I've read (and don't understand) how $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[\left|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)\right|\right]=0$$ from the *dominated convergence theorem*. It seems like an easy implicaiton, but I don't find an approach to show it.

Comment: You seem to neglect some other assumptions.  What properties does the sequence have?  For example, if $X_n=X$ and $Y_n=Y$ for all $n$, then why should limiting behavior converge to 0?

Comment: @Michael You're right, I'd missed some important properties (edited now).

Comment: Could anyone explain to me, why four people have voted to close this question?

Comment: @oxbadfood Well, probably because an (very important) assumption was missing. (I haven't downvoted your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the Lipschitz-continuity and boundedness of $f$ that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|) &\leq K \int_{d(X_n,Y_n) \leq R} d(X_n,Y_n) \, d\mathbb{P} + 2\|f\|_{\infty} \mathbb{P}(d(X_n,Y_n) >R) \\ &\leq K R + 2 \|f\|_{\infty} \mathbb{P}(d(X_n,Y_n) >R). \end{align*}$$

Letting $n \to \infty$, we get

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)|)  \leq K R.$$

Letting $R \to 0$ finishes the proof.

Comment: I don't think that we need $R$ and I don't understand why we need to deal with $2\left\|f\right\|_\infty$ instead of $\left\|f\right\|_\infty$ itself. Furthermore, I'm wondering why the statement uses the limit superior instead of the usual limit. Since the integral of a nonnegative function is nonnegative, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[\left|\cdots\right|\right]=0$$ should imply the existence of the limit.

Comment: @oxbadfood A priori we do not know that $\limsup \mathbb{E}(\dots)=0$. *After* we have shown that this holds true, we get automatically $\lim \mathbb{E}(\dots)=0$. Regarding $2 \|f\|_{\infty}$: Well, by the triangle inequality: $$|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)| \leq |f(X_n)|+|f(Y_n)| \leq 2 \|f\|_{\infty} $$ ... or what estimate do you use? (In any case, the constant $2$ doesn't matter at all.) Regarding $R$: I need it in my proof.

Comment: You don't need the triangle inequality. Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous and bounded, we've got $$\left|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)\right|=\underbrace{1_{A_n^C}\left|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)\right|}_{\le Kd(X_n,Y_n)}+\underbrace{1_{A_n}\left|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)\right|}_{\le\left\|f\right\|_\infty}$$ (where $A_n$ is defined in my answer). So, you don't need $R$.

Comment: @oxbadfood I've never claimed that there are not other ways to prove this. However, in **my** proof I need $R$ and $2\|f\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: Don't mind. I just thought I'd missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A_n:=\left\{Kd\left(X_n,Y_n\right)>\left\|f\right\|_\infty\right\}$$
Since $X_n,Y_n$ maps to $E$ and $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $E$, we've got $$\operatorname{E}\left[\left|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)\right|\right]\le k\operatorname{E}\left[\underbrace{1_{A_n^C}d\left(X_n,Y_n\right)}_{=:Z_n}\right]+\left\|f\right\|_\infty\operatorname{P}\left[A_n\right]$$ by the monotonicity and linearity of expectation. Now, $Z_n\le\left\|f\right\|_\infty<\infty$ is a random variable with values in $[0,\infty)$ which converges stochastically to $0$ (by assumption). Thus, the dominated convergence theorem yields $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[Z_n\right]=0$$ Due to the stochastic convergence we've got $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{P}\left[A_n\right]=0$$ in addition, which completes the proof.