# Does convergence in probability imply weak convergence on an arbitrary metric space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(S, \rho)$ be a metric space and write $\mathcal{S}$ for the corresponding Borel sigma-field. Let $(X_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables converging in probability to a random variable $X$, by which I mean: for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have as $n \rightarrow \infty$
$$ \mathbb{P}( \rho(X_n, X) > \epsilon ) \rightarrow 0 $$

Is it true that $X_n \Rightarrow X$ in the sense of weak convergence?

Comment: Unless $(S,\rho)$ is separable, in general $\rho(X_n,X)$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

It is true.

This is a consequence of the following result, also found in Achim Klenke's book *Probability theory* (Thm. 13.18 / Cor. 13.19):
Let $ X, X_1, X_2\ldots  $ and $ Y, Y_1,Y_2 \ldots $ random variables with
values in a metric space $ (S,ρ)  $. Assume $ X_n → X $ weakly and $
ρ(X_n,Y_n) → 0   $  in probability. Then $ Y_n → X $ weakly. Considering the special case $X_n = X$ then shows that convergence in probability implies weak convergence.

To show this, note that due to the [Portemanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), we can test weak convergence using bounded Lipschitz continous functions instead of bounded continuous functions.

Next, for any $f$ Lipschitz and bounded, it holds that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[\left|f(X_n)-f(Y_n)\right|\right]=0$ (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205134/if-f-is-lipschitz-x-n-converges-in-distribution-and-dx-n-y-n-converges). The assumption of a separable metric space made there is needed merely to ensure that something like $ρ(X,X_n)$ is measurable). Armed with this, we find
\begin{align*}
    \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{|\mathbb{E}[f(Y_n)] - \mathbb{E}[f(X)]  |} 
    \leq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{|\mathbb{E}[f(X)] - \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]  | } +
    \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{| \mathbb{E}[f(X_n) - f(Y_n)] |}  = 0,
\end{align*}
hence $ Y_n \rightarrow X $ weakly.